# Can I write a plug in for Microsoft SQL Enterprise Manager which changes the query window background

Tags: sql-server

Can I write a plug in for Microsoft SQL Enterprise Manager which changes the query window background if the query window points to a production database?

Comment: Good Question!  Let's make sure we account for "USE [DBName]" directives, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Enterprise Manager doesn't have a plug-in framework for you to hook in to.

Answer (score 0):

I see this has already been answered but I'm going to add this in case it helps future readers.  The Enterprise Manager has been replaced by SQL Management Studio.  Management Studio does have support for add-ins.  Also, when you register a server in the properties window you can associate a custom color with the connection.  Whenever you open a query window, the status bar along the bottom of the window will be this color.  We have an Access database that contains information about the systems we support, including SQL Server and database names.  I wrote a SQL Powershell script that registers all of the servers and sets their custom color to Green, Yellow, and Red for Development, Acceptance, and Production.  It doesn't change the entire query window color but it might be useful to you.